# In UV photoelectron spectroscopy why are filled orbitals seen at a higher binding energy?

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

[image]

I understand that the partially filled Ni intersects the Fermi level as there is a change from filled to unfilled orbitals. But what is the explanation for the lower binding energy of the filled 3d Cu orbital. Surely there would be greater electron-electron repulsion resulting in higher kinetic energy of the electrons due to more shielding, which corresponds to a lower binding energy?